# nginx rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

HI,

Given the following apache/mod_rewrite rule taken from .htaccess within minify directory on the server:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]=.*)  index.php?$1  [L,NE]
```

what will be the nginx compatible equivalent of it? I have tried:

```
rewrite ^/minify/([a-z]=.*)  minify/index.php?$1 break;
```

but that doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something like this and it's working for me

```
rewrite ^/min/([a-z]=.*) /min/index.php?$1 last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like [bbPress's code](http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/nginx-rewrite-rules-for-pretty-permalinks).